# jquery form does not reload the page

Tags: jquery, forms

I'd like to mimic html form behaviour using jquery. When clicking on a button, I want to delete a comment using:

```
$(".delete_comment").live('click', function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var param_delete_comment = btn.attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/you/ajax_delete_comment/'+param_delete_comment,
        type: 'POST',
        async: false

    })
    return false;
});
```

The server side processing seems to work (it deletes the comments and return the comment bit of the html), but the comment bit is not reloaded.

The only difference I can see compared to a html form is that the latter has

```
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

in the request headers.

Anybody can help?

Thank you

Jul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the AJAX call correctly returns the HTML you need, but you don't do anythign with it. Use the `success` callback:

```
$(".delete_comment").live('click', function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var param_delete_comment = btn.attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/you/ajax_delete_comment/'+param_delete_comment,
        type: 'POST',
        async: false, // NB: this is usually a bad idea.
        success: function(data) {
            // data is the HTML returned by ajax_delete_comment; use it, e.g.:
            $('#comment').replaceWith(data);
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

Comment: +1 for your comment... async: false // NB: this is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to reload the page? If the server side code is working and the comment is deleted, **just remove the comment from the DOM on the client side**, using the `remove()` method.

```
success: function(){
        $('comment').remove(); //might need to change the selector here, 
                               //but you should be able to handle that 
    }
```

Comment: I need to reload the whole comment html bit, because it also shows the number of comments

Comment: You could decrease that by one maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I think the "return false" at the end of your click event is preventing the form from submitting.

On a side note, why use ajax if you are going to refresh the entire page?  Something to think about.

Comment: right.  I would think you'd want to just re-load the DIV the contains the comments.  otherwise, why use AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

is `$(".delete_comment")` a submit button? if so the return false is your problem. Otherwise, 
ajax specifically is meant to AVOID page reloads .. Use a `form.submit()` call instead